# How can I delete multiple characters in my bash script?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I want to create a bash script on Linux, which will only tell me my ip-adress, netmask and broadcast. Right now it shows more than that though, so I would like to remove a specific number of characters from my variable.

Example:

What I have

```
ip=Hello world!
```

What I want

```
ip=Hello
```

So how can I remove a specific amount of characters from the back of the variable?

I tried multiple things that I found online, but couldn't get it working the way I want it to.

Comment: Please show the relevant code and state the exact problem or error. A description alone is not enough. Also see [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: @jww When I post a question it says that I should only show the relevant part of the code, there is no error with my code or porblem, so why would I inculde it here? I just didn't know how to do it and couldnt find any answer when searching for it. I got the answer I needed, and I don't know what I should have done better with this question ^^ Im open to suggestions, so what do you think is wrong with my question? Or what would I need to change so its better?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

with `bash`'s substring extraction:

```
$ my_var="Hello world!"
$ my_var=${my_var:0:-6}
$ echo $my_var
Hello
```

Comment: Thanks it worked! Could you explain what exactyl we're doing here ${my_var:0:-6}? Or how is that called, so I can look it up myself :)

Comment: @ManuelSarica, ok, look at "Substring Extraction" section on http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/string-manipulation.html

Answer (score 0):

You could pipe through grep and only output the matching portion

```sh
echo "ip=hello world" | grep -o "ip=\w*"
```

Output: `ip=hello`

Answer (score 0):

Another point is you can use sed command.

For, example

```
$ my_var="Hello world"
$ my_var=$(echo $my_var | sed -e 's/ .*//')
$ echo $my_var
Hello
```

or another approach using cut

```
$ my_var="Hello world"
$ my_var=$(echo $my_var | cut -d ' ' -f1)
$ echo $my_var
Hello
```

Important - do not type `!` symbol in double-quotes